# how to click on a button with CSS selector

Tags: button, css-selectors

I have submit and confirmation button in two different pages and both has same CSS selector. The confirmation button does not have any id. As I use CSS selector to click on Submit button , because of this I am not able to click on Confirmation button with same CSS selector.

Please help with me other possible ways to click on confirmation button. Please note I tried with all the supportable locators in web driver.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you can't provide an example of the code you're using.

Comment: I too really want to see the code you use to click on a button with CSS.

Comment: This is the code found out when I do inspect element of that button....<input class="btn-blue mL30 mR10 font-size5 inquiry-submit" value="XXXX" type="Submit">..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute selector:

```
input[type="submit"]
```

will select the `<input>` with `type="submit"`.

```
input[type="button"]
```

will select any `<input>` with `type="button"`.

---

**More about the attribute selector:**

When using the *attribute selector*, you don't have give the value of the attribute.

For example:

`img[title]` will select any `<img>` which has a `title` attribute, regardless of what that title is.

Furthermore, you can select elements by **value-fragment** of a given attribute:

- **^=** : `img[title^="Just released -"]` selects any `<img>` which has a `title` which **begins** with *Just released -*
- **$=** : `img[title$=" (2012])"]` selects any `<img>` which has a `title` which **ends** with * (2012)*
- ***=** : `img[title*="th"]` selects any `<img>` which has a `title` which **contains the letters** *th* anywhere in the title.
- **~=** : `img[title~="Copyright"]` selects any `<img>` which has a `title` which **contains the word** *Copyright*.